# The group of isometries of Shahshahani metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

**Edit: 28 January 2023** I just realized that this metric is frequently used in this paper
https://hal.science/hal-01382281/document

Let  $$M=\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid x_i>0,\;i=1,2,\ldots,n\}$$
For  $X=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in M$ put $|X|=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

We  consider the  Shahshahani Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$  with  diagonal  tensor  metric $g_{ii}=\frac{|X|}{x_i}$.

What is the  dimension  and  the precise structure  of the  group of  all isometries of  $(M,g)$?

Comment: Are you asking about global isometries rather than infinitesimal isometries?  In the former case, it's just the symmetric group on $n$-letters acting as permutations of the $x_i$ (when $n>1$).  The Lie algebra of Killing vector fields, though, has dimension $\tfrac12n(n{-}1)$ (when $n>1$) and is isomorphic to the Lie algebra of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Yes I was asking for global isometries however your answer about Lie algebra of Killing vector field is very helpful. I try to understand the details of both part. Thanks for this very helpfull comment.

Comment: @RobertBryant  I can not understand why Killing vector fields is isometric to the Lie algebra of $SO(n)$. For $n=2$, what is a precise Killing vector field for that metric? This may help me to find all Killing vector fields.

Comment: Actually, what I said above in the case $n=2$ is not correct because, in the case $n=2$, there are more Killing fields.  (See the note in my answer below.)  However, when $n>2$ there are no more Killing fields than those generated by the obvious $\mathrm{SO}(n)$-action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is that, if you set $x_i = {u_i}^2$ where $u_i>0$, this becomes a diffeomorphism of $M$ with itself with the property that, in the $u$-coordinates, the Shahshahani metric becomes
$$
g = 4({u_1}^2+\cdots+{u_n}^2)\bigl({\mathrm{d}u_1}^2+\cdots + {\mathrm{d}u_n}^2\bigr).
$$
Clearly, this metric is just the flat metric in the $u$-coordinates on the positive orthant times the squared '$u$-distance' from the origin.  When $n\ge2$, any rotation in the $u$-coordinates would preserve the metric on the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$, but it wouldn't preserve the positive orthant, which is $M$.

When $n=2$, this is a flat metric:  Set $z = u_1 {+} i\,u_2$. then $g = 4 z\bar z\, \mathrm{d}z\circ\mathrm{d}\bar z =\mathrm{d}w\circ\mathrm{d}\bar w$ where $w = z^2 = (u_1 + i\,u_2)^2 = ({u_1}^2{-}{u_2}^2)+ i\,(2u_1u_2)$.  Thus, $w:M\to\mathbb{C}$ isometrically embeds $(M,g)$ as the upper half-plane in $\mathbb{C}$ when $\mathbb{C}$ is given its standard metric.  The global isometries are the translations by a real number in the $w$-coordinate together with reflection in the imaginary axis. Meanwhile, the Lie algebra of Killing fields has dimension $3$ instead of $1$.

However, when $n>2$, the metric is *not* flat, and the Killing fields are the infinitesimal generators of the obvious $\mathrm{SO}(n)$-action, as can be seen by direct calculation or conversion to 'polar coordinates'.  Meanwhile, globally on $M$, you only have the rotations and reflections (in the $u$-coordinates) that preserve the positive orthant, and this is just the permutations in the $u_i$, which is the permutations in the $x_i$.

Comment: I wanted to write something similar, but I was missing one argument.  You write, correctly, that any rotation preserves the metric.  But the question remains: are there additional transformations that preserve the metric?  Without the factor $(u_1^2 + \cdots + u_n^2)$, in the Euclidean case, the obvious answer would be no.

Comment: @jarauh:  I have added a note to address your concerns.  You are right that the case $n=2$ is special.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Thank you for extending your comment to this very helpful answer.

Comment: @RobertBryant Is there a uniform upper bound for the cardinality of the isometric group of a Riemannian metric on the plane whose isometric group is a finite group. According to your answer the Shahshani metric, which can be counted as a metric on the whole plane(after a diffeomorphism), has an order 2 isometric group. Now, can one imagine metrics whith arbitrary large order of finite isometry group?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  Yes, there are metrics with arbitrarily large finite group of isometries.  For example, for any $n\ge 1$ you can have a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose only isometries are the rotations by $2k\pi/n$ about the origin, a cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: I am  sorry if  my  question is  elementary: What is  my  mistake in the following: We  consider the  metric $g$ in the  third line of  your  answer. We  consider  $g$ as  a  metric  on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$. Then $g$ is  invariant under $O(n)$ action.So the  isometric  group of this  Riemannian manifold  has  sharp dimension. Does not imply this that the metric is flat? So the restriction of metric  to M is  flat too. What is  my  mistake?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  I'm not sure what you mean by 'sharp dimension'.  When $n>2$, the isometry group of the metric considered to be on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ is exactly $\mathrm{O}(n)$, and it is not flat (there are no 'translations').  In particular, the 'global isometry group' has dimension strictly less than the (maximum possible) $\tfrac12n(n{+}1)$.  Another way to see this is that the sphere $|u|=1$ under the metric $g$ is isometric to the standard Euclidean sphere of radius $2$ (instead of radius $1$), even though the $g$-distance from $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is only $1$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Yes  I  understand. by  sharp  dimension(may be  not  a  good  terminology) I  meant "Maximum possible  dimension". after your  explanation I realize that the  isometric  group  does not  have  maximum possible  dimension.Thank you.